# remove specific keys from boost unordered_map

Tags: c++, boost

I have a boost unordered_map container (mymap), and I want remove some keys which predictor returns true for them.

```
boost::range::remove_if(mymap, ((boost::bind(&mesh::type, (boost::bind(&map_type::value_type::first, _1)))) == EDGE) );
```

mesh::type is defined as following:

```
class mesh
{
  ...
  Type type() const;
  ...
}
```

and "EDGE" is one of the "Type enum".

here is the error I got:

```
error: non-static const member ‘const mesh std::pair<const mesh, std::vector<std::vector<Point> > >::first’, can’t use default assignment operator
```

I use boost version 1.53 and C++03.

Comment: Please always post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you need to lookup by something else than the map key, this is usually a sign that you need to have (a) multiple indexes or (b) heterogenous lookup

Answer (score 2):

```
// define this, either as a static member function or in a 
// private namespace...
bool is_edge(const map_type::value_type& vt)
{
  // note: concerned with the key, not the data
  return vt.first.type() == EDGE;
}

// ... and avoid all the unreadable bind nastiness completely
boost::range::remove_if(mymap, is_edge);
```

Comment: ＋1 for this. This looks like it is maybe what the OP wants to achieve